Scroll down the RecyclerView to the last PagingDataAdapter item in Paging3
I am developing a chat screen, all messages are immediately saved in Room and then I receive them via Paging3.
My problem is that I can't scroll down to the last aitem after sending a message. When I try to use recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastPosition) the list scrolls down to the last item in the Paging3 page.
Adapter initialization
linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = true
binding.messageRecycler.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
binding.messageRecycler.adapter = messagePagingAdapter

binding.layoutQuickMessages.visible = false
viewModel.readMessages(sessionId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->
    messagePagingAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, data)

Adapter
class MessageListPagingAdapter(
    private val onRichMessageStart: (Message.ExerciseType) -> Unit,
) : PagingDataAdapter<Message, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(MessageDiffUtilItemCallback()) {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        position: Int,
    ) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        if (item != null) {
            when (item.type) {
                Message.Type.RICH -> {
                    if (holder is MessageListAdapter.RichMessageViewHolder) {
                        holder.bind(item)
                    }
                }

                Message.Type.RECEIVED -> {
                    if (holder is MessageListAdapter.ReceivedMessageViewHolder) {
                        holder.bind(item)
                    }
                }

                Message.Type.SENT -> {
                    if (holder is MessageListAdapter.SentMessageViewHolder) {
                        holder.bind(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int,
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =
        when (viewType) {
            Message.Type.RECEIVED.ordinal -> {
                val binding =
                    ItemMessageReceivedBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false,
                    )
                MessageListAdapter.ReceivedMessageViewHolder(binding)
            }

            Message.Type.SENT.ordinal -> {
                val binding =
                    ItemMessageSentBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false,
                    )
                MessageListAdapter.SentMessageViewHolder(binding)
            }

            Message.Type.RICH.ordinal -> {
                val binding =
                    ItemRichMessageBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false,
                    )
                MessageListAdapter.RichMessageViewHolder(binding, onRichMessageStart)
            }

            else -> {
                val binding =
                    ItemMessageSentBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false,
                    )
                MessageListAdapter.SentMessageViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        when (getItem(position)?.type) {
            Message.Type.RECEIVED -> Message.Type.RECEIVED.ordinal
            Message.Type.SENT -> Message.Type.SENT.ordinal
            else -> Message.Type.RICH.ordinal
        }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView
    }
}

ViewModel
fun readMessages(sessionId: String): LiveData<PagingData<Message>> =
    repository.readMessages(sessionId).asLiveData().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

Repository
fun readMessages(sessionId: String): Flow<PagingData<Message>> {
    val pageConfig = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 20,
        enablePlaceholders = false,
        prefetchDistance = 10,
    )
    return Pager(
        config = pageConfig,
        pagingSourceFactory = { SelfTestHistoryPagingSource(sessionId, therapyDao) },
    ).flow.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}

PagingSource
class SelfTestHistoryPagingSource(
    private val sessionId: String,
    private val dao: TherapyDao,
) : PagingSource<Int, Message>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Message> {
        val position = params.key ?: 0

        return try {
            val response = dao.readMessages(sessionId, 20, position * params.loadSize)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response,
                prevKey = if (position == 0) null else position - 1,
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else position + 1,
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Message>): Int? =
        state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
}

I couldn't find the right information.

Resolve
       messagePagingAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
      override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
        if (linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout) {
          binding.messageRecycler.scrollToPosition(0)
        } else {
          binding.messageRecycler.scrollToPosition(messagePagingAdapter.itemCount - 1)
        }
      }
    })


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
